# file_get_contents in php returns empty string

Tags: php, angularjs

[SQL Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eT99P.jpg)[my loadtable function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmNpH.jpg)
If i delete the button in the table . through the id the sql database didnt get delete

I have searched a lot about this related article . . I couldn't find the solution
passing my id in http delete request. when I have var_dump the variable its giving empty string.
It didn't give error it is just gave data deleted correctly message. but didn't get deleted

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in dated">
<td>{{x.Id}}</td>
<td>{{x.Name}}</td>
<td>{{x.Phone}}</td>
<td>{{x.Status}}</td>
<td><button name="btn" value="Update" ng-click="updatefn(x.Id,x.Name,x.Phone,x.Status)">Update</button></td>
<td><button name="btn" value="Delete" ng-click="deletefn(x.Id)">Delete</button></td>

</tr>


$scope.loadtable=function()
{
 $http({
  url:'select.php' ,
  method: 'GET', 
}).then(function(get_response){
    alert(JSON.stringify(get_response));
    $scope.dated=get_response.data;
    $scope.status=get_response.status;
    $scope.value="ADD";
                           },function(get_response)
{
});
}


$scope.deletefn=function(id)
{
$http({
url: 'delete.php',
method:'DELETE',
data:id,
headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8' }
  
}).then(function(res)
{
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res)
    
    );
},function(res)
{
    alert(res);
});
```

---

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")); 
if(is_null($data)){
    echo 'This line is printed, because the $var is null.';
}
var_dump($data);//empty string
 if(count(array($data)) > 0)  
 {  
 $id_del = $data->send_id;
      
 $query = "DELETE FROM society_tour WHERE id='$id_del'";  
    
if(mysqli_query($connect, $query))  
 {  
echo 'Data Deleted correctly';  
}  
else
{  
  echo 'Error';
  }  
}
```

Debugging info:

Warning provided by PHP:

> Warning: Attempt to read property "send_id" on string in
> **C:\xampp\htdocs\delete.php** on line **12**

Console log results:

```
console.log(id) // 123
console.log(typeof(id)// string
```

Comment: What is the content of `id` in your JS when you run this code? Give us an example

Comment: @ADyson If i alert the response i got the following data.....{"data":" string(3) \"123\"\n<br />\n<b>Warning</b>:  Attempt to read property \"send_id\" on string in <b>C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\delete.php</b> on line <b>12</b><br />\nData Deleted correctly  \r\n","status":200,"config":{"method":"DELETE","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"delete.php","data":"123","headers":{"Content-type":"application/json;charset=utf-8","Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":"OK","xhrStatus":"complete"}

Comment: Thanks, that's useful, but it isn't what I asked you. Although it does give a clue - you are sending a string in the request but PHP is trying to treat it like an object. If what you are sending is a valid JSON object then you'd have to decode it first. But I don't know what you're really sending - that was what I was asking you to provide.

Comment: @ADyson I have updated my code here also encoded the php input value. . still data didnt get delete. pls look at it

Comment: I asked a simple question, which you need to answer: _What is the content of `id` in your JS when you run this code?_  . Use the JS debugger or the network tool to inform you.

Comment: @ADyson I'm getting hesitate to ask you again. .But really i don't know what is the content of the ID. . While I run the code which id I have selected that id only passing I think. .

Comment: `really i don't know what is the content of the ID`...so then you need to go and find out. I told you how to look for it - was there something you didn't understand from my description? If so please let me know what you are confused about, and I could try to clarify.

Comment: For the simplest technique you could write `$scope.deletefn=function(id)
{ console.log(id); console.log(typeof(id));` ...etc. And then run the delete code, and tell me the output of those two console.log statements. But for future, please learn to use your browser's Network tool to examine the contents of your AJAX requests.

Comment: @ADyson yeah sure I will learn it quickly. .thank you so much for your reply.. and for  console.log(id)// 123, console.log(typeof(id)// string

Comment: Ok So you're literally sending "123" by itself to the server. That isn't JSON, and it isn't an object, it's just a plain string. So I suggest 1) remove `headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8' }` from the $http options, 2) change `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));` to just `$id_del = file_get_contents("php://input");` and 3)  remove `$id_del = $data->send_id;`.

Comment: Also change `if(is_null($data)){` to `if(is_null($id_del)){` and change `var_dump($data);//empty string
 if(count(array($data)) > 0)  
 {  ` to `var_dump($id_del);//empty string
 if(!empty($id_del)  
 {  `

Comment: No problem. Shows the value of debugging! I added proper answer below, so you can mark it as "accepted" - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're literally sending "123" by itself to the server. That isn't JSON, and it isn't an object, it's just a plain string.

So I suggest

1. remove `headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8' }` from the $http options,
2. change `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));` to just `$id_del = file_get_contents("php://input");`
3. remove `$id_del = $data->send_id;`
4. change `if(is_null($data)){` to `if(is_null($id_del)){` and change `var_dump($data);//empty string  if(count(array($data)) > 0)    {`   to `var_dump($id_del);//empty string  if(!empty($id_del)    {`

This will make PHP read just the plain string and use that as the ID, without attempting to decode it as JSON or extract values from within it.